# How to exporting materials from Substance painter into blender with same lights and shading

Tags: texturing

In substance painter I have applied various materials. I like the shade and reflections on my object.

But when I import it into Blender I notice when I set up the material nodes, its not the same like it's SP. I then need to tweak the world node to try get a match. is there a way to bake the lights, or export the materials to look as it is, when I import it into Blender?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your materials nodes? Also make sure to use the correct format for the images, for example: Normal in Open GL instead of Direct X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get the environment texture used in Painter. (So, it's more a Substance Painter answer than a Blender answer)

They are located, depending on your version, under "YourSubstancePainterPath/ressources/shelf/allegorithmic/environnements" or "YourSubstancePainterPath/ressources/Starter assets" or something similar.

To find which one you're using, you can check in Display Settings :
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, that's what I was looking for.